# C program hangman game freezing at lvl 10

Tags: c

I have a school project and it is a hangman game in c, there are 20 levels and each level the user have to choose 2 options, whenever the program reaches level 10 and the user cleared that it freezes

- here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
int main() {
    system("cls");
    srand(time(NULL));
    int n,
    l=0;

    char guessWords[][25]= {
        "red",
        "blue",
        "green",
        "yellow",
        "orange",
        "tiger",
        "dolphin",
        "penguin",
        "january",
        "april",
        "july",
        "october",
        "december",
        "pizza",
        "banana",
        "chocolate",
        "purple",
        "dog",
        "cat",
        "elephant"
    }

    ;

    char guessWords2[][25]= {
        "pseudocode",
        "loop",
        "programming",
        "algorithm",
        "function",
        "parameter",
        "argument",
        "array",
        "recursion",
        "flowchart",
        "identifier",
        "terminator",
        "index",
        "element",
        "declaration",
        "primitive",
        "integer",
        "float",
        "statement",
        "operands"
    }

    ;
    int numLives=4;
    int numCorrect=0;
    int oldCorrect=0;

    int letterGuessed[10]= {
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0
    }

    ;
    int quit=0;
    int loopIndex=0;
    int reguessed=0;
    char guess[20];
    char letterEntered;

    int usedIndices[40]= {
        0
    }

    ;

    // game loop
    for (int i=0; i < 20; i++) {
        int randomIndex;
        int lengthOfWord;

        do {
            randomIndex=rand() % 20;
        }

        while (usedIndices[randomIndex]);
        usedIndices[randomIndex]=1;
        lengthOfWord=strlen(guessWords[randomIndex]);
        int randomIndex2;
        int lengthOfWord2;

        do {
            randomIndex2=rand() % 20;
        }

        while (usedIndices[randomIndex2]);
        usedIndices[randomIndex2]=1;
        lengthOfWord2=strlen(guessWords2[randomIndex2]);
        l++;
        printf("WELCOME TO HANGMAN!\n");
        printf(" 1. Option 1\n");
        printf(" 2. Option 2\n");
        printf(" Choose: ");
        scanf("%d", &n);
        // Consume the newline character in the input buffer
        while (getchar() !='\n');

        switch (n) {
            case 1:
                system("cls");

            while (numCorrect < lengthOfWord) {
                printf("\n\n  LEVEL %d \nHangman Word: ", l);

                for (loopIndex=0; loopIndex < lengthOfWord; loopIndex++) {
                    if (letterGuessed[loopIndex]==1) {
                        printf("%c", guessWords[randomIndex][loopIndex]);
                    }

                    else {
                        printf(" _");
                    }
                }

                printf("\n");
                printf("Remaining life: %d\n", numLives);
                printf("Number Correct So Far: %d\n", numCorrect);
                printf("Letter Guessed: ");

                for (int y=0; y < lengthOfWord; y++) {
                    printf("%c ", guess[y]);
                }

                printf("\nEnter a guess letter:");
                fgets(guess, 20, stdin);

                if (strncmp(guess, "quit", 4)==0) {
                    quit=1;
                    break;
                }

                letterEntered=guess[0];
                reguessed=0;
                oldCorrect=numCorrect;

                for (loopIndex=0; loopIndex < lengthOfWord; loopIndex++) {
                    if (letterGuessed[loopIndex]==1) {
                        if (guessWords[randomIndex][loopIndex]==letterEntered) {
                            reguessed=1;
                            break;
                        }

                        continue;
                    }

                    if (letterEntered==guessWords[randomIndex][loopIndex]) {
                        letterGuessed[loopIndex]=1;
                        numCorrect++;
                    }
                }

                if (oldCorrect==numCorrect && reguessed==0) {
                    numLives--;
                    printf("Sorry, wrong guess\n");

                    if (numLives==0) {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                else if (reguessed==1) {
                    printf("Already Guessed!!\n");
                }

                else {
                    printf("Correct guess :)\n");
                }
            }

            // while loop
            break;
            case 2: system("cls");

            while (numCorrect < lengthOfWord2) {
                printf("\n\n  LEVEL %d \nHangman Word: ", l);

                for (loopIndex=0; loopIndex < lengthOfWord2; loopIndex++) {
                    if (letterGuessed[loopIndex]==1) {
                        printf("%c", guessWords2[randomIndex2][loopIndex]);
                    }

                    else {
                        printf(" _");
                    }
                }

                printf("\n");
                printf("Remaining life: %d\n", numLives);
                printf("Number Correct: %d\n", numCorrect);
                printf("Letter Guessed: ");

                for (int y=0; y < lengthOfWord2; y++) {
                    printf("%c ", guess[y]);
                }

                printf("\nEnter a guess letter:");
                fgets(guess, 20, stdin);

                if (strncmp(guess, "quit", 4)==0) {
                    quit=1;
                    break;
                }

                letterEntered=guess[0];
                reguessed=0;
                oldCorrect=numCorrect;

                for (loopIndex=0; loopIndex < lengthOfWord2; loopIndex++) {
                    if (letterGuessed[loopIndex]==1) {
                        if (guessWords2[randomIndex2][loopIndex]==letterEntered) {
                            reguessed=1;
                            break;
                        }

                        continue;
                    }

                    if (letterEntered==guessWords2[randomIndex2][loopIndex]) {
                        letterGuessed[loopIndex]=1;
                        numCorrect++;
                    }
                }

                if (oldCorrect==numCorrect && reguessed==0) {
                    numLives--;
                    printf("Sorry, wrong guess\n");

                    if (numLives==0) {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                else if (reguessed==1) {
                    printf("Already Guessed!!\n");
                }

                else {
                    printf("Correct guess :)\n");
                }
            }

            // while loop
            break;
            default: printf("Invalid option\n");
            break;
        }

        if (quit==1) {
            printf("\nThe user quit early\n");
            break;
        }

        if (numLives==0 && n==1) {
            printf("\nYou Lose!\n The word was: %s\n", guessWords[randomIndex]);
            break;
        }

        else if (numLives==0 && n==2) {
            printf("\nYou Lose!\n The word was: %s\n", guessWords2[randomIndex2]);
            break;
        }

        else {
            printf("\nYOU WIN!!! :)\n");
            numLives=4;
            numCorrect=0;
            oldCorrect=0;
            loopIndex=0;
            for (int j=0; j < 20; j++) letterGuessed[j]=0;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

what seems to be the problem, why is the program freezing

Comment: Do me (and most likely yourself) a favor and change your habits concerning blank lines and the location of `; `.

Comment: Run the program from a debugger and when it freezes, hit break.

Comment: There are only four comments in this program, and zero of them are useful. As you have not explained anything to yourself in the code, you have also not explained anything to us in your question. We are left with the options of either ignoring you, or running your program and experimenting to figure out what your first paragraph even means. I will say that on a quick skim-read of the code, this line looks like an unexploded bomb: `for (int j=0; j < 20; j++) letterGuessed[j]=0;` -- see if you can figure out why that is. GCC's address sanitizer will probably help you there.

Comment: I recommend using self-explaining identifiers (e.g. constants) instead of magic numbers like 25, 10, 20, ... and to use sbufunctions instead of huge `main()` functions.

Comment: Write a clear function that uses an ANSI escape instead of `system("cls")` which is windows specific.

Comment: Consider using a `const char *[]` array for your guessed words instead of fixed sized strings.  Instead of hard-coding two array names use a pointer to either array so you don't have to repeat the same code twice.  Alternatively, use a an array of `struct word { const char *word; int option }`

Comment: You should check the return value of `scanf()` otherwise you may be operating on an uninitialized variables.  `while (getchar() !='\n')` is not safe as `getchar()` will return `EOF` if stream is closed (with ctrl-D on Linux).

Comment: Instead of `printf("a"); printf("b");` you can do `printf("a" "b")` when split over multiple lines it's easier to read then print per string.

Comment: You can initialize an array with `int letterGuessed[10]= {0};`.  Less error prune than writing it out.

Comment: If you have one word left the random select has `19/20 = 95%` of not finding an unused slot per loop iteration.  Maybe count however many words `n` are left then pick 1 random numberf from `[0; n[`.

Comment: Consider breaking `main()` into smaller functions.

Comment: Strive for minimizing scope of variables.  `int n` could be moved down just before the `scanf()`.

Answer (score 1):

You access the `int letterGuessed[10]= { ... }` array out of bounds with:

```
for (int j=0; j < 20; j++) letterGuessed[j]=0;
```

The minimal fix is to change the variable declaration to:

```
int letterGuessed[20] = {0};
```

It's really the maximum number of unique letters of your words plus however number of allowed invalid guesses.  I would use `LETTERS + MAX_LIVES` where `#define LETTERS 25` for English, and `#define MAX_LIVES 4`.

As `letterGuessed` is an array you can also use `sizeof letterGuessed / sizeof *letterGuessed` instead of `20`.

Finally, as the point of that loop is to zero the array consider using `memset()` which is highly optimized for this task.